# Error while connecting to WebSocket from Agular with SockJS

Tags: angular, spring-boot, websocket, sockjs

I try to implement a WebSocket-Connection into my Angular Project. For the Backend i use SpringBoot.
I found a tutorial and did all the steps form it. Here is the link to the tutorial
https://www.codesandnotes.be/2020/03/31/websocket-based-notification-system-using-spring/

But i always received an error when i try to connect to the WebSocket.This is the error message from google chrome:

> GET "mylocalhost" net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

If i uses firefox i get an in my oppinon more detailed error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource...

Here is my WebSocketConfigClass:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
      registry.enableSimpleBroker("/notification");
      registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/swns");
  }

  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
      registry.addEndpoint("/notifications")
              .setAllowedOrigins("*")
              .withSockJS();
  }
}
```

Isn't it enough to set AllowedOrigings?

Here is the connect method:

```
    connectClicked() {
    if (!this.client || this.client.connected) {
        this.client = new RxStomp();
        this.client.configure({
            webSocketFactory: () => new SockJS("http://localhost:8080/notifications"),
            debug: (msg: string) => {
                console.log(msg);
            }
        });
        this.client.activate();

        this.watchForNotifications();

        console.info("connected!");
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I try to use sever sent events instead, but i get the same error message when i call:

```
const source = new EventSource("http://localhost:8080/stream-sse");
```

Here is the code in my controller:

```
 @GetMapping("/stream-sse")
  public Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>> streamEvents() {
    return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
           .map(sequence -> ServerSentEvent.<String>builder()
                   .id(String.valueOf(sequence))
                   .event("periodic-event")
                   .data("SSE - " + LocalTime.now().toString())
                   .build());
}
```

I wounder why i can call other methods in the rest controller if ther is an cors problem .

Answer (score -1):

shouldn't

```
new SockJS("http://localhost:8080/notifications")
```

be

```
new SockJS("ws://localhost:8080/notifications") for http
new SockJS("wss://localhost:8080/notifications") for https
```

Comment: SockJS does not support ws or wss protocall